# What do I need to upload a file to a form using php?

Tags: php, html, file, upload

I'm creating a job application form in which a user adds his resume and it's attached to an email, everything worked fine for file less than 1 MB size, if it's more when I click submit the server takes so much time then gives me a server timeout error.

This is the html:

```
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="personalCV">CV</label>
        <input
         name="personalCV"
         type="file"
         class="form-control"
         id="personalCV"
         placeholder="Attach CV"
         style="height: auto;"

         value="<?php if (isset($personalCV)){echo $personalCV;} ?>"
         required>
         <span>File Shouldn't exceed 2MB, and must be of formats .doc, .docx, .pdf</span>

      </div>
```

This is the php:

```
  if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {

    //assign variables//
    $firstName = filter_var($_POST['firstName'] , FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $lastName = filter_var($_POST['lastName'] , FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $email = filter_var($_POST['userEmail'] , FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
    $phoneNum = filter_var($_POST['phoneNum'] , FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
    $position = $jobTitle;
    $message = filter_var($_POST['message'] , FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $path = 'upload/' . $_FILES["personalCV"]["name"];
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["personalCV"]["tmp_name"], $path);
```

I guess the problem is that when i click on the form submit button the file starts to upload which takes some time more than the server timeout,  is there a way where the user waits for the file to upload first (maybe use a progress bar), then after it uploads user clicks submit form and it's sent to email, or will the problem still persist.

Comment: There shouldn't be a server timeout while the file is uploading. Timeouts only happen when the connection is idle.

Comment: Is your script taking a long time to process the file? It should just use `move_uploaded_file()` to save the file somewhere, and process it offline.

Comment: 1 MB is tiny it should upload in under a second, are sure this is the issue

Comment: I updated the post with my code , I'm using move_uploaded_file() to save it in an upload folder inside my project, but still it takes  too much time, then gives me this error : fatal error maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in xampp

Comment: @tim it works fine if file is under 1MB the problem is when it exceeds approx. 1.5 MB

Comment: check  `$_FILES[personalCV']['error']` for an error code, might help

Answer (score 0):

PHP has several configuration options to limit resources consumed by scripts. By default, PHP is set to allow uploads of files with a size of 2MB or less.

Try increasing the following values in php.ini, for example:

```
memory_limit = 32M
upload_max_filesize = 24M
post_max_size = 32M
```

Comment: I already did that , and I can send the email but only on my local host , is there a way I could upload the file before I click the submit button